# How to Disable NTLM authentication over HTTP in IIS

Tags: http, iis, ntlm, remoteapp

A recent security scan of our network reported the vulnerability "NTLM Authentication Host Information Disclosure" in our RemoteApps (Microsoft RemoteApp).

Here's an article that explains it: https://blog.gdssecurity.com/labs/2014/2/12/http-ntlm-information-disclosure.html

The only solution I have been told is to "Disable NTLM authentication over HTTP". I've seen this in several posts, but none really go into detail about what specifically that entails.

I thought it would be a setting in IIS, but I cannot locate anything that even looks remotely like that.

How would I go about disabling NTLM over HTTP?

Would this prevent RemoteApps from working?

Answer (score 0):

I found it under

Authentication >> Windows Authentication >> Providers